# How to cut shape on top of another one in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, illustrator-effects

I'm working on Adobe Illustrator CS6 and I've a question about how to cut an area from a shape using another shape. To clarify the point, I've the first image below.

What I want to do, is to 'cut' the circle shape from the rectangle, so that the rectangle will have a centre transparent hole; image (2)

And of course, if I change the background, it'll look like image (3)

[image: Illustrator cut shapes]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The pathfinder tool is your friend !

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html
[image]

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what the cut tool does.